# Query parse.com by time, not date

Tags: .net, parse-platform

Is there a way to query from parse.com *CreatedAt* column by the time only? My goal is to query all the records that were *CreatedAt* between say 6 and 12 o'clock regardless of the date (though I will need to attach some date range also). I am using parse's .NET API. In my mind I thought something like this might work, but sadly all I got was *InvalidOperationException*:

```
pQuery = from hit in pQuery 
    where ((DateTime)hit.CreatedAt).Hour >= 6 
       && ((DateTime)hit.CreatedAt).Hour <= 12
    select hit;
```

Of course I always could filter results after the query using business logic, but that would hinder the performance. Would love a query solution.

Comment: That pQuery on both sides of the = looks odd to me

Comment: Well it is relating to the previous query. You could imagine second _pQuery_ as being just `ParseObject.GetQuery("Hits")`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do it the way you're thinking - the `createdAt` field is just a UNIX timestamp. Instead, you could try adding a new field (or fields) to track the time. Create a `beforeSave` method for that class that populates those fields anytime a new object gets created. Then you can query against those new fields.

The tricky part here will be dealing with timezones, so take that into consideration.